# Printing out two dimensional array in awk with blanks

Tags: arrays, awk

I trying to take a file like that shown below and output it in which `$1` is the columns and `$2` is the rows.

```
$ cat file
8       A       11.56
6       A       1.46
10      A       1.60
7       A       19.36
9       A       7.09
9       C       0.63
8       C       3.64
7       C       5.20
8       G       12.20
6       G       1.62
7       G       17.39
10      G       2.12
9       G       7.77
9       T       0.67
8       T       3.07
7       T       4.62
```

the desired output is:

```
B       6       7       8       9       10
A       1.46    19.36   11.56   7.09    1.60 
C               5.20    3.64    0.63  
T               4.62    3.07    0.67
G       1.62    17.39   12.20   7.77    2.12G
```

I have written the following code to get it most of the way there, but there are some errors still.

```
awk '
BEGIN{OFS="\t"
        print "B",6,7,8,9,10
        }
{
a[$2""$1]=$3
b[$2]
}
END{ORS="\t"
for (c in b)
        {
        print c
        for (i=6;i<11;i++)
                {
                for (r in a)
                        if (r==c""i)
                                print a[c""i]""c""i
                }
        print "\n"
        }
}' file
```

output >

```
B       6       7       8       9       10
A       1.46A6  19.36A7 11.56A8 7.09A9  1.60A10
        C       5.20C7  3.64C8  0.63C9
        T       4.62T7  3.07T8  0.67T9
        G       1.62G6  17.39G7 12.20G8 7.77G9  2.12G10
```

I can't figure out why there are tabs at the beginning of the last three rows, and I am not sure how to put a space in when there is no data (I will probably just format my input file to have zeros for those values).

Comment: Don't set `ORS`. Set `OFS` and use printf for the fields then `print ""` when you are done.

Comment: that works for half the problem, can you think of a way to print a " " for positions like C6, which are absent form the input list?

Comment: `printf ""` when you can't find a value for that field (else of `r==c""i` I *think*).

Comment: I tried that, it inserts a space or "" for every record in the infile...  Unless you can think of another approach, I'll just insert a record into the in file with a 0 for `$3`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do this:

```
awk -F "\t" -v OFS="\t" '
    {v[$2,$1] = $3; k[$2]} 
    END {
        print "B",6,7,8,9,10
        for (key in k) {
            printf "%s", key
            for (i=6; i<=10; i++) {
                printf "%s%s", OFS, ((key SUBSEP i) in v ? v[key,i] : "")
            }
            print ""
        }
    }
' file
```

output

```
B       6       7       8       9       10
A       1.46    19.36   11.56   7.09    1.60
C               5.20    3.64    0.63    
T               4.62    3.07    0.67    
G       1.62    17.39   12.20   7.77    2.12
```

Comment: Nice. You are missing the "tag" appended to each field though.

Comment: that's not a problem, I just put the tag there to keep track of things to make sure everything was going where it was suppose to...

Comment: this worked with one tweak.  I had to replace `: ""` with `: "\t"` other wise the C and T rows did not have tabs at the 6 position.  Also can you point me to documentation that talks about using `?` and `:`, I couldn't find any in the C docs I looked at.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Conditional-Exp.html#Conditional-Exp

Comment: That will print a blank instead of the value if some field evaluates to numeric zero and it may produce a syntax error on some awks due to the unparenthesized ternary expression.

Answer (score 0):

Not fix on 6-10, can be any string in $1

```
awk '{a[$2 FS $1]=$3;b[$1];c[$2]}
END{ printf "B\t" ;for (i in b) printf i OFS;printf RS
     for (i in c) 
      { printf i OFS
        for (j in b)
            printf a[i FS j] OFS
        printf RS
      }
    }' OFS="\t" infile
```

Answer (score 0):

If the OP accepts a solution that depends on `gawk` (specifically depending on multidimensional arrays and the `asort` builtin) here it's mine

```
% cat tabular.awk
   {col[$1]=$1;row[$2]=$2;val[$2,$1]=$3}
END{asort(col); asort(row)
    printf "B" ; for(j in col) printf "%10d", col[j]; print ""
    for(i in row) {
        printf row[i]
        for(j in col) printf "%10s", val[row[i],col[j]]
        print ""}}
% awk OP.dat -f tabular.awk
B         6         7         8         9        10
A      1.46     19.36     11.56      7.09      1.60
C                5.20      3.64      0.63          
G      1.62     17.39     12.20      7.77      2.12
T                4.62      3.07      0.67          
%
```

---

Should the OP need a different formatting of the numerical data, s/he can modify the statement

```
val[$2,$1] = $3
```

in the default treatment of every line to, e.g.,

```
val[$2,$1] = sprintf("%10.2e", $3)
```